# Is it possible to cancel a touchmove event during scrolling?

Tags: javascript, scroll, touch, touch-event

If I try to cancel a touchmove event after it has scrolled past a certain point on the screen, it produces the error `[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.`

In this case, canceling scrolling in progress is exactly the effect I want. Is there something I can do to cancel the touchmove event anyways? If not, what are some workarounds I could consider?

I'm canceling the event with this code:

```
if(scrolledTooFar) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
  return false;
}
```